# How to split train/test datasets according to labels' classes

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I faced a problem while I using sklearn.train_test_split().
Here is the code I use.

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X_source, Y_source, test_size=0.3)
```

The shape of X_source is (2427,features_size), Y_source is (2427,1). And there are 65 different classes of labels in Y_source, what I mean is that Y_source is a matrix length of 2427 and the value from 1 to 65.

My problem is that, while I use train_test_split, the output (ytrain/ytest) only contains some of labels' class not all classes. I think it is because the method just split 30% of the whole data but don't care about their labels classes. What should I do to deal with it, I want to make sure the output contain all the labels' classes, and every classes are splited 30% into the train set. Does there have a function can do this? Or I need to reshape my data according to different labels' classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument `stratify=Y_source` to maintain the proportions after splitting.

Comment: Thanks! it works.

Comment: Glad to help! You can accept the answer if that solved your problem.